# PHP strcmp function with file

Tags: php

I have a text file as

```
hi
hi
bye
bye
```

And php code to read the text file.  The strcmp compares each line of the text with the given string `'bye'` and if they are equal it needs to print `$line`.  But nothing is printed on the screen.

```
$handle = fopen("input.txt","r");

while(!feof($handle))//scanner.hasnextline
{
    $line = fgets($handle);
    //echo $line;

    if(strcmp($line,'bye')==0)
    {
        echo $line;
    }

 }
```

But if i give `if(strcmp('bye','bye')==0)` the `$line` gets printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But `strcmp("bye\n",'bye')` is not. With `fgets` the new line is included in the return value. Use `trim` if you want to remove it.

```
$line = trim(fgets($handle));
```